# In my graduation android app , i want to use OTP in forget password (using phone number not email) through realtime fire base . what is the solution?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, forgot-password, reset-password

In my app I want to use the OTP to reset password.
I use realtime firebase and my app is in kotlin
what is solutions?

I tried to use SMS [use of sms manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsTug.png)
but the message sent from the phone number i entered.